# Round down and group by decade php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I know its probably a very stupid question, but is there a simple way to round down from a date format like such:

1992-12-11 ( Thats in a mysql database )

I would really like to run a query and then turn 1992 into 1990 and then group by all 1990 entries.

I dont even know where to start with it, and all i can seem to find is decimal rounding etc but it could get messy and not always work.

If anyone can offer a suggestion using mysql and or some php i would really appreciate it.

--------- update ------------

```
$sql_decade = "SELECT date FROM archivals WHERE status=1 GROUP BY YEAR(date) DIV 10";

$result = mysql_query($sql_decade) or die(mysql_error());

while($r= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$decade = $r['date'];

echo $decade;

}
```

Stil not quite rounding down.

Just gives me the full dates still?

Comment: FLOOR(YEAR / 10), this will make 1992, into 199.2 and you will get 199 as result.

Comment: Under what circumstances would decimal rounding not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform [integer division](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) on the year:

```sql
GROUP BY YEAR(date) DIV 10 -- 1993 becomes 199, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, checking will get back to you.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion being the first here thank you but for some strange reason i don't get the round down.
I have updated the post to have the query in it.

Comment: @jonnypixel: You would also need to use the same expression in the select list.

Comment: @jonnypixel: You could also use `ROUND(YEAR(date), -1)` to round to the nearest decade, e.g. 1993 becomes 1990 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a query like:

```
     SELECT count(*)
      FROM table
  GROUP BY FLOOR(YEAR(date_column)/10)
```

Comment: Thanks, checking this too will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

FLOOR(Table_Name/10)*10 AS decade